# Camera properties for 3d using specular reflection

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Could any one help in clarifying the following description taken from the article "Local Shape from Mirror Reflection" by Savarese, Chen and Perona.

"Let c be the center of projection of the camera. The image plane is positioned l distance units in front of c, perpendicular to the view direction v. Given a scene point p let q be the image of p observed on the image plane through a specular reflection on the mirror surface at r."

1. To my understanding both c, v and l are properties of the camera, so how can I find them?
2. As p moves along the scene plain q and r shift respectively are c,v and l constant or should a new center of projection, image plane and view direction be calibrated separately for each point?

[Image for the setup of the system:](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=2305a07)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C and v are not intrinsic properties of the camera, they are just its location and orientation. However, l is the focal length, which is an intrinsic parameter. Both intrinsic and extrinsic parameters can be recovered through a calibration procedure. If you like matlab, google for Jean-Yves Bouguet's camera calibration toolkit. It has also been ported to OpenCV since forever, if you'd rather C or C++.

The extrinsic parameters change only if the camera is moved relative to the scene. The intrinsic ones change if anything in the lens is changed, e.g. by refocusing or changing the aperture (the f-stop). Neither change with the exposure time (it only affects how many photons reach the sensor).

Note that with today's lens mounts (screw, bayonet) and sensor sizes and resolutions (a few tens of mm and several megapixels across) it's **very** easy to "move" the camera: just touching the lens is often enough to move its center by a few pixels and its axis by a few minutes of arc. If repeatability is paramount you may want to look into getting a special/custom lens mounts and very rigid camera stand/support. In any case your software will need to be robust with respect to small camera motions